# Testing Spring Controllers : Invoke service methods or mock results

Tags: java, spring, unit-testing, spring-mvc

When testing Spring Controller with Spring Test MVC we are currently setting  up the database with DBUnit and we do not mock the service methods out.

Although this slows down our tests to some degree(We use an embedded H2 database), our tests are much cleaner without having to stub methods and create test data builders/ factory methods.

What are your thoughts on this? Are we going to regret this approach, can you make any recommendations on alternative approaches?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would rather say, that Mocking should only be used when it is needed to test a class or component standalone behavior and the mocked feature comes in production from outside your application (an email server for instance). The behaviour is much more predictable, than if you are crossing multiple layers, to access DB.
There is a good article on this:
http://blog.trifork.com/2012/12/11/properly-testing-spring-mvc-controllers/

But on the other hand you have integrations tests, unit, functional, etc, when it's better to avoid Mocks. It really depends what you really need.

Please read also this, there is a good discussion on it:
[Integration test per layer is a good practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32974845/integration-test-per-layer-is-a-good-practice)

Comment: Thank you, I think since the services that our controllers are calling are not remote calls I am going to let the controllers execute the service calls and label these as integration tests.

I think we will only break out Mockito if there is really a need.